# Fixed header is hiding vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to incorporate this jquery plugin - https://gist.github.com/3819758, to a table so that it can have a fixed header.
In my case the table is too wide and so the header that gets generated, hides the vertical scrollbar - http://jsfiddle.net/NWV73/4/

I am not able to get around this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an actual http://jsfiddle.net for testing instead of an image? That usually speeds up the process. And what is the actual detailed expected behavior?

Comment: Added the jsFiddle to the question.

Comment: Additionally, if you see the image here - http://i.imgur.com/efwgj.png, you will notice that the header overflows outside the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize div scrolling with JavaScript:

```
$(".table-content").scroll(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $header = $(".header-fixed");

    $header.css("margin-left", 0 - $this.scrollLeft() )
});
```

See also updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NWV73/21/

Comment: The scroll helps in moving the header, which is great. Thanks. But additionally my concern was that the top arrow of the vertical scrollbar comes into view only when the table is scrolled to the right most end. Is there anyway to make it visible irrespective?